# How to get the n numbers in only one line and put them into a list and according to the list, print characters in python?

Tags: python

I want the n numbers to be entered on one line, with just spaces. I'm trying to use .split in `ai = [int(input()) for ai in range(n)]`, but the following error appears:
`ai = [int(input()) for ai in range(n)].split(' ')`
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2 6 3 7 1'`
So I don't know which part of the code I should change to reach the correct format.
The wrong input:

```
n: 5
2
6
3
7
1
```

The correct input and its respective output:

```
Input:
n: 5
2 6 3 7 1 

Output:
**
*
***
*
*
```

The wrong code is:

```
n = int(input('n: '))
ai = [int(input()) for ai in range(n)]
for i in ai:
    if i == 1:
        print('*')
    elif i == 2:
        print('**')
    elif i == 3:
        print('***')
    elif i > 3:
        print('*')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. But I guess you want to validate that the amount of entered numbers match `n`, right?

```
n = int(input('n: '))
ai = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
for i in ai:
    if i == 1:
        print('*')
    elif i == 2:
        print('**')
    elif i == 3:
        print('***')
    elif i > 3:
        print('*')
```

In the case you want to validate the input of `n` numbers:

```
n = int(input('n: '))

ai = []
while len(ai) != n:
    ai = [int(i) for i in input('Enter ' + str(n) + ' values: ').split()]

for i in ai:
    if i == 1:
        print('*')
    elif i == 2:
        print('**')
    elif i == 3:
        print('***')
    elif i > 3:
        print('*')
```

Comment: @scilli Exactly!

Comment: @scilli Thank you so much!! Now it's working according to all conditions of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is in one line:

```
>>> print('\n'.join('*' * (n if n in (2, 3) else 1) for n in map(int, input().split())))
2 6 3 7 1
**
*
***
*
*
```

Note that prompting for the number of inputs ahead of time isn't needed if you're entering them on one line, since the end of the string tells you when the user is done entering numbers.

The key thing is to apply the `int` function to the list produced by the `split()` function, rather than attempting to turn the entire string into an `int` before you `split` it.

With a superfluous `input()` included in the single `print` call it'd be:

```
>>> print(input() * 0 + '\n'.join('*' * (n if n in (2, 3) else 1) for n in map(int, input().split())))
5
2 6 3 7 1
**
*
***
*
*
```

Comment: Wow! It's an amazing solution. In just one line you wrote the several lines I had written! Thank you very much, but only one thing is missing and it's the number of inputs before this.

Comment: You can technically make it a one-line solution that includes that prompt by adding `input() * 0 +` so that you call the `input()` function and then discard its result.  You don't say what you want to actually do with the input if it doesn't match the quantity of numbers the user enters on the next line, so presumably just getting the input and throwing it away is fine.  :)

Comment: Just for learning more :) Well, I'm a beginner in programming and for curiosity, I would like to know more and challenge myself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you tried on it to convert the whole string, with the whitespaces between the numbers, to int.

the solution is to use `str.split()` on the input to get a list with the inputted numbers, and then convert each number in the list to `int` using `map()` function

Try this code:

```
n = int(input('n: '))
ai = list(map(int, input().split()))
for i in ai:
    if i == 1:
        print('*')
    elif i == 2:
        print('**')
    elif i == 3:
        print('***')
    elif i > 3:
        print('*')
```

Comment: Thanks, but another error appears:                                                                                         `ai = list(map(lambda x int(x), input().split()))
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Thank you so much! It's showing the correct input and output I needed.

Comment: Using map is not necessary and makes the code quite complex. a basic list comprehension does the job as well: `ai = [int(i) for i in input().split()]`

Comment: I eddited the code, so now it don't use lambda function in the map. In this format, it's faster to use map.

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the input *before* you can convert it to integer values:

```py
n = input('n: ')
ai = [int(a) for a in n.split(' ')[1:]]
```

Comment: Thank you, but the output is changing into something not desired.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I forgot that your first input number is just the number of the following inputs. I edited my answer to ignore the first number.